# How to get original html in Froala editor

Tags: froala

I want to get changes between the html after and before changes, The method i see in the docs is just for get the current html after editing:

```
$(selector).froalaEditor('html.get');
```

How can i get the original source ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(selector).data('froala.editor')._original_html
```